# JSP ignores some css

Tags: java, css, jsp, tomcat, web

i have a problem with java web app.

I have a page and a css. CSS linked correctly and jsp sees it. But after adding some new styles, jsp ignores it.

Did someone get same problems?

That's the jsp head

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mainStyle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/buyingTicket.css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            #bus{
                background-image: url("pictures/bus-disabled-buyingPage.png");
            }
            #tram{
                background-image: url("pictures/train-disabled-buyingPage.png");
            }
            #troll{
                background-image: url("pictures/trolleybus-disabled-buyingPage.png");
            }
            #metro{
                background-image: url("pictures/metro-disabled-buyingPage.png");
            }
        </style>
```

And this is an example of css.

```
#tram{
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("pictures/bus-disabled-buyingPage.png");
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I have to add styles in jsp head to let this work, it happens with all my jsps now. I have to add new style not to ccs, but to head of jsp.

Comment: What did you add within css? In which css did you add something? Possible problems are caching in the browser (try F5) or overridden css (buyingTicket.css overrides layouts of mainStyle.css with same ids/attributes/names).

Comment: mainStyle and buyingTicket do not override each other. I add background image in buyingTicket, but jsp does not see it. Even jsp style head does not work. Have to us js - window.onload function to set those images. Cache is not the answer. F5 does not work at all.
Can It be a problem with tomcat?

Comment: If caching is an issue, use Control + Shift + R to reload the page without using cached items.

Comment: Make sure your new files are deployed to the server: check that the css files in the webapps folder of your tomcat contain your changes.

Comment: I don't think so. Are you sure about the URL of the background image you used that it is the same as within the onload javascript function?

Comment: I am sure)
Have 0 thoughts about this problem, srsly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspects:  Cache, File-Location, Wrong-Syntax

**Cache:**

Cache could be tricky. Just to be sure if it is cache.

- check the links of the `styles/mainStyle.css` and `styles/buyingTicket.css` are accessible directly in your browser.
- check the links to the background images `pictures/bus-disabled-buyingPage.png` ...
- Press CTRL+ F5 and see it any difference. (If so, cache was the issue)
- Try in different browser/device.
- Some Browser-Addons can interfere, try stating the browser in safe mode.

**File-Location:**

- check you workspace, if there are multiple files with the same name.
- clean and redeploy

**Wrong-Syntax:**

It could be also wrong syntax in some of your files. Validate the content:

- CSS: http://www.css-validator.org/
- HTML: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thx a lot for detailed answer, gona try these.